# Icons and picture not showing up? Any idea why?

Tags: wordpress

I'm in the process of making some changes to my site, and I'm running a test version at http://wpdallas.com/test

If you look at the top right there should be a image and some social media icons (like at http://noahsdad.com/) but I can't seem to get it to show up right. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Edit: here is the css code on the child theme that I"m using. The css is there, but for some reason it's not overriding the parent css.)

```
    /*  
Theme Name: Standard Preview Child Theme
Description: Standard is a meticulously designed and coded theme for professional blogging. It adapts to mobile devices and individual posts can be styled distinctly for words, images, quotes, links, videos, or statuses. It includes a light and dark style sheet and precision, zero-config SEO techniques are built-in. Visitors will love it. Search engines will love it. And you will love it.
Author: 8BIT
Template: Standard
*/

@import url("../Standard/style.css");

.iframe { width:580px !important; height: 326px !important; }

/* Social Updates */
#text-25    {position:relative;}
#social         {background:url(http://wpdallas.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/noah-front-page-standard.jpg) no-repeat; height:300px; width:300px; position:relative;}
.social_icon        {height:32px; width:32px; display:inline-block;}
.social_trans       {height:32px; width:32px;}
#social_dock        {position:absolute; top:70px; left:8px;}
#social_dock a *    {border:0;}
#subscribe_dock     {position:absolute; bottom:12px; left:8px;}
#social #facebook   {background:url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/social-sprite-2.png) no-repeat;}
#social #twitter    {background:url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/social-sprite-2.png) no-repeat -32px 0px;}
#social #youtube    {background:url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/social-sprite-2.png) no-repeat -64px 0px;}
#social #rss        {background:url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/social-sprite-2.png) no-repeat -96px 0px;}
#social #pintrest   {background:url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/social-sprite-2.png) no-repeat -128px 0px;}
#social #googleplus {background:url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/social-sprite-2.png) no-repeat -160px 0px;}

#email-subscription-box {width: 244px !important; text-algn:center; margin-top:15px;}

/* Add Border Strip on Post Titles */
h2.title   {font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; border-left: 5px solid #2e3192; padding-left: 8px; 
    -webkit-transition-property: *; 
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; 
    -moz-transition-property: *; 
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
   }
h2.title:hover  {border-left: 5px solid #d5145a; padding-left: 5px;}

[css].bsap-wrapper { -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; background: #FFFFFF; border-radius: 4px; padding: 15px 0 10px 15px; }
.bsap-wrapper .bsap a { margin-right: 17px; }[/css]

.content iframe { width:580px; height: 326px; }
```

Comment: This is so funny. Hi Rick, you know my wife Gretchen through the web. Our son Julian is also special needs. If you need any one-on-one help let me know. tsherman57 gmail

Comment: Wow, that is funny! Are you a nerd like me? Ha,ha. (And do you know what's going on with my css?)

Comment: Which social media icons are you referring to? I see some at the very top in a blacker bar. At Noah's dad I see social media links in what looks to be a right hand side widget. If you are using widgets we'll need to know which one. Also, you should be aware of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com which is better at answering WP questions vs. SO is best for programming questions.

Comment: If you look on NoahsDad.com/ you'll see the picture on the top right. It's just a text widget with some CSS...not a 'real" widget. If you look at the test site (http://wpdallas.com/test) you'll notice the background image and icons aren't showing up on the top right hand side. Not sure what's going on. My CSS looks correct.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you can say I'm a nerd. I have 10k+ SO rep from nerding =). Make sure you read the faq and try to include code when posting questions whenever possible. People are very helpful when you follow the rules and not so nice when you don't! http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the picture reading 'Hi, I'm Noah' and also the icons, the images don't show up because the background images aren't specified in your css.

At NoahsDad.com, the Hi I'm Noah picture is displayed with the following CSS

```
#social {
   background: url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/bg2.jpg) no-repeat;
   height: 260px;
   width: 260px;
   position: relative;
}
```

The http://wpdallas.com/test/ site does not include this css at all. You should check that your CSS references are correct and loading.

**Update:**

Your CSS file is at

```
http://wpdallas.com/test/wp-content/themes/Standard-Child-Theme-1/style.css
```

According to the [Wordpress docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) this isn't the correct path setup for a child theme. A child theme goes in the parent's directory.

```
public_html
  wp-content
    themes (directory where all themes are)
      twentyten (directory of our example parent theme, Twenty Ten)
        twentyten-child (directory of our child theme; can be named anything)
           style.css (required file in a child theme; must be named style.css)
```

I think that you should repost this question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com because WP API isn't really my strong suit. Phrase it like so:

I have a child theme called Standard-Child-Theme-1. The style.css file for it is not being loaded. My site is http://wpdallas.com/test. Can someone please help me troubleshoot why it is not being included?

Comment: Hmm. I'm looking at my style sheet, and it does have this CSS in there. It's a child theme so I"m wondering if that has thing to do with it? This is what's in my CSS for this child theme.  I can't figure out how to insert my code here for you to see...When I try to indent it goes to 'save edits".....?

Comment: Here it is. http://wpdallas.com/test/wp-content/themes/Standard-Child-Theme-1/style.css

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean. The CSS in my child is just importing the parent theme style sheet: http://wpdallas.com/test/wp-content/themes/Standard/style.css Also I'm not sure what you mean when you say the site is using http://wpdallas.com/test/wp-content/themes/Standard-Child-Theme-1/standard_framework/css/standard_framework.css?ver=3.3.1 ?

Comment: Hey Rick, I updated my answer with a few pointers. I have to go to bed now because I have an 8am conference call. Anyways, I can check back tomorrow evening after work. Probably best if you ping me at my gmail address.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think you put the incorrect path in your comment. The parent and the child theme go into the same folder /themes. It looks like your saying the child goes into the parent folder, this isn't what it says on the wordpress doc. I'm confused how I have an incorrect path? The Standard-Child-Theme is in the same folder as the parent theme (Standard) and the css of the child theme is in the Standard-Child-Theme-1 folder, like the wordpress doc says. Here is a quote from that page "A child theme resides in its own directory in wp-content/themes. "

Comment: In your comment you said the child theme goes into it's parent directory, but according to the wordpress docs it says the child theme goes into it's own directory. Maybe I'm missing something. Thanks for your help though. :)

Comment: @RickSmith - yeah you are right. They are sibling directories. For some reason I read that as parent/child relationship.

Comment: No biggy. I figured it out. I had to change a file in the parent directory. Here is what was going on. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri  I changed 'get_template_directory_uri()' to 'get stylesheet directory uri() and everything worked. Wow, that took all night. Need to sleep (nap) now. :)

Comment: However, I am still getting some 404 errors that I can't figure out when I look at the code. For instance that http://wpdallas.com/test/wp-content/themes/Standard-Child-Theme-1/standard_framework/css/standard_framework.css?ver=3.3.1 which is strange because the site is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

I had this same/similar issue with these icons appearing.  Though my CSS seemed to be set up properly, I still wasn't seeing the icons.

Copying and pasting the folder "images" from the parent theme into the child theme's folder cleared the issue up immediately.